# Responsive images positioned over image

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have setup a jsfiddle of what i'm trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/3936/

```
#counter {
    position: relative;
}
#over {
    position:absolute;
    left:33%;
    top:43%;
}
```

The image of the cat is my background image which resizes as the browser resizes.

The ball image is absolutely positioned over the cat. How can I get the ball image to resize and stay in the same position as it is my default?

Comment: try `position:fixed;` instead

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set your `#counter` div to `display: inline;` or add a wrapper with `display: inline;` and set the `max-width` of `#over` to for example `10%` ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/7239/)):

```
#counter {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
#over {
    position:absolute;
    left:33%;
    top:43%;
    max-width: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Exactly where I was going with it. You need your absolutely-positioned element positioned with respect to an element that stays the same size as the cat image. Here it is with the left position tweaked: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/MgcDU/3939/

Comment: From playing with the fiddles it seems like the main difference is adding:
url('http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
 url('http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css');
Adding display:inline and max-width to the first fiddle doesn't make a difference