# Responsive Click Area using bootstrap and CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

I'm trying to make a responsive click area for an image that will have 2 links, one in each rectangle in the picture below. Here is the code I'm using right now. It doesn't have any mapping and I will explain it further why:

```
  <figure id="vpg">
     <img  src="{{asset('img/click area.png')}}" class="img-responsive" width="1024" height="768"alt=""/>
```

I tried using map class and coord points, it worked well but it's not responsive.
Then I searched and tried to use Matt Stow plugin: https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps but it didn't worked. I believe it is because of bootstrap or something because his example did not worked with the img-responsive class.

This is the picture: 
[image]

The point is, I need to use this class img-responsive, is there something I'm missing? How should I proceed? Is there a way to do it with css? I found this example but I couldn't understand it: 
http://techlife.samsung.com/the-perfect-game-day-set-up.html

Comment: If I understand what you're asking correctly, I would create those two divs separately and absolutely position them on top of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vinicius Pacheco Vieira answer and link works. This all done for you in grid system like bootstrap or foundation use. Download Foundation here [Foundation Grid system](http://foundation.zurb.com/) and read the documentation on their site to learn more about grid system. Everything comes down to pre-made div's that are predefined in their width, so when you place image inside it will scale with this div that is around the image. With Foundation you get full CSS file where all basic setup is made but if you want to change something just find it in code using inspector element (F12 key) in browser and point to element to inspect. This will show you which file is controlling which class and what's inside....etc..

Comment: Thank you for your information! I will take a look in their stuff about grid system, it certainly will help me understand more.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this img tag without set width and height. This way you can control width and height in css file, by manipulating its style. Try using % instead of px, as this way % will stay relative to screen width.
If this doesn't help, then get rid of width and height in img tag and surround your img and figure in new div (using grid system, if you are using bootstrap its already made inside css file). This way grid system will control width of image and child elements inside it.
Hope I answered your question.

Comment: I've used your idea but I did not quite understand how to use the grid system. I found a question with similar problems, I believe they have used  what you said: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363029/responsive-images-positioned-over-image

Answer (score 0):

Using the concepts mackelele and 4ever Youngz said I ended with this code that solved this situation.

```
<style>
#counter {
          position: relative;
      }
      #background{


      }
      #squaremoreleft{
        position:absolute;
        width: 20%;
        left:5%;
        top:51%;
      }
      #squareright{
        position:absolute;
        width: 20%;
        left:26%;
        top:51%;
      }
</style

<div class="container">
          <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
              <div id="counter">
                <img id="background"src="{{asset('img/imgbackground.png')}}" class="img-responsive"/>
                <a href="link1">
                <img id="squaremoreleft"src="{{asset('img/squareleft.png')}}" class="img-responsive" />
                </a>
                <a href="link2>
                <img id="squareright"src="{{asset('img/squareright.png')}}" class="img-responsive" />
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

The code is inspired in this question [Responsive images positioned over image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363029/responsive-images-positioned-over-image) and its source code: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/12389/