# Absolute positioning of element in responsive header

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I'm trying to get exactly the same effect as here: [Responsive images positioned over image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363029/responsive-images-positioned-over-image) , so I want my absolute positioned elements to stay in the same place but get smaller or bigger when the browser is being sized. I tried many different possibilites, before I worked with this code, but I don't understand why my wrapping container (id="wrapper") is placed under the image. And to get the question mark on the image I would need to use minus percentage. In the example I copied from another question in stackoverflow there are bootstrap styles. I don't know and I don't want to use bootstrap though. I will be very grateful for all suggiestions what I'm doing wrong.

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
#questionMark {
    position:absolute;
    left:33%;
    top:-43%;
    max-width: 10%;
}
```

This is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8obzf2c8/2/

Comment: img {
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wrapper has property `display: inline;` so it behave like a fe. `span` element, it is not a block.

Change `display: inline;` to `display: inline-block;` so the wrapper behaves like inline container. You will also need to change this weird `top: -43%;` to fe. `top: 43%` as things will get more normal and predictable.

Comment: It worked exactly how I wanted it to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`inline` elements doesn't get the height of the elements inside them.
You should remove the `display: inline` from the `#wrapper` element.

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
#questionMark {
  position:absolute;
  left:33%;
  top:-43%;
  max-width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id=wrapper>
  <img src="http://e.allegroimg.pl/s400/19/53/89/71/60/5389716014"/>
  <img id="questionMark" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/speech-bubble-with-question-mark_318-78800.png"/>
</div>
```

> I also set `margin-top` to make sure the question mark image is in the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:inline-block;` instead of `inline`

```
#wrapper {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}
#questionMark {
position:absolute;
left:33%;
top:43%;
max-width: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will make the image placed in the center and will also be responsive with all screen sizes.

```css
#wrapper {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

img{
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

#questionMark {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
max-width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id=wrapper>
  <img src="http://e.allegroimg.pl/s400/19/53/89/71/60/5389716014"/>
  <img id="questionMark" src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/speech-bubble-with-question-mark_318-78800.png"/>
</div>
```

Hope this helps,