# Responsive-Image positioned on another image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have 2 images. One image (through background-url) with position relative is the main image and another image (through background-url) with position absolute is placed above the first image.

when i shrink the browser the 2nd image doesn't follow responsiveness. Is there a way to do?

Thanks in advance!!

```
// 1st image// 

  &main-background { 
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-image: url("images/campaign/1-bg.jpg");
  }

// 2nd image// 

 &__main-bg {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    color: $blue-2017;
    background-image: url("images/campaign/main-1.jpg");
    box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;

    @include media($small-screen) {
      font-size: 0.8em;

    }
  }
```

Comment: I think there is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363029/responsive-images-positioned-over-image

Comment: I have checked that already and it doesn't work that way. thanks

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: No i am not using Bootstrap. Have to do through media-queries.

Comment: Try including the 2 bootstrap css files (bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css) and it should work. Check the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/7239/

Answer (score 0):

What is the value for this variable for $small-screen ?
Is there a need to us that ?

```
@include media($small-screen) {
```

}

Try removing those lines and see if it works . If it doesn't.
Try using reducing the percentage of your image 2 and using brute force Css ( !important ) at the end of each line in your Css for your second  image. I am pretty sure that there are some Css overwriting your second image